# How to analyze with SonarQube a project where sources and tests are in the same directories

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have a project to analyze which is only based on Angular framework.
The main issue I have is that both source and test files are on the same directories, divided into features.

Here is an example of my structure:

```
+- client
|   +- features
|   |   +- home
|   |   |   +- home.js          [source code]
    |   |   +- home.spec.js     [test code]
        |   +- home.html
        |   +- home.less
        +- admin
        |   +- admin.js         [source code]
        |   +- admin.spec.js    [test code]
        |   +- admin.html
        |   +- admin.less
        ...
```

In my `sonar-project.properties`, it seems impossible to set a pattern instead of a path (for ex. `sonar.tests=client/**/*.spec.js`).

Is there a way to run an analysis with this kind of structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to SonarQube mailing list, the solution is to set the following properties:

```
sonar.sources=client
sonar.tests=client

sonar.exclusions=**/*.spec.js
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.js
```